No UWP workload available in Visual Studio 2022 Installer
I'm struggling with finding the UWP template in my Visual Studio 2022 Community version 17.10.4. I've installed the program with default settings and then wanted to install the 'Universal Windows Platform development' workload, but I can't find it anywhere. Has someone had a similar problem?
I've tried installing the newest Windows SDK, but that didn't help. I've also searched the internet to find a solution but I didn't find anything helpful.

You mean this? https://i.sstatic.net/82byuscT.png Are you using the installer or just trying to find it in Visual Studio itself?

Hi, yes I mean that. I am looking for it in the installer and there's nothing like that.

Starting with Visual Studio 17.10, it was replaced with "Windows application development":

In Visual Studio 17.10, the new “Windows application development” workload is now available for developers to jump right in and get started with writing stylish, modern, and fast WinUI apps using .NET or C++ with only one click. This workload replaces the older “Universal Windows Platform development" workload with tools aimed at the latest generation of WinUI + the Windows App SDK.

You should instead see a "Windows application development" workload for you to install:


Thank you so much! I didn't notice that

Unfortunately, even after installing that the option for a blank UWP application still doesn't appear :/

I managed to get the template option back by checking "Universal Windows Platform tools" on the right side of the installer under "Installation details" > "Windows Application Development" > "Optional".
Frustratingly I couldn't find it under "Individual Components" but it is here.
